# Can you make a graph without storing values in a list first?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

For example if I had:

```
maxsize = 1000000;
lis1 = {};
For[i = 1, i <= maxsize, i++,
 lis1 = Append[lis1, i]]

ListLinePlot[lis1]
```

In the current process a number is stored to `lis1` for each iteration and after the loop has ran 1 million times, a graph is then created.  However, as more and more values are being stored, the process seems to slow down.  So there are two questions I have:

1. Is there a limit to the size of a list you can have in Mathematica?  Is 1000000 entries in a list too many?
2. Assuming list size is not an issue, is there any way to directly just plot a value obtained from the loop without having to store it first?  So in this example, instead of obtaining:

   lis1={1,2,3,4....1000000}

Is it possible to just take the integer given by each iteration of the loop and plot it to a graph without storing that value in a list beforehand?

I know there may be other ways to make the graph which this specific loop shows, however I'm working on a a bit of code which happens to use a `For` loop in the same manner as the example above so any work arounds here in relation to that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your list can be made using `Range[1, 1000000]`.  Plot it directly by doing `ListPlot[Range[1, 1000000]]`.  I suspect, however, that this isn't really the function you want to plot, so you might need to provide more details about your actual problem.  One thing I'll say is that if you're using a `For` loop, you're likely doing something "wrong" in *Mathematica*, as you can often avoid loops.  The construction you're using is the reason it's so slow.  It needs to remake the list each step of the loop, and its gets bigger and bigger as you go. Use `Table` or other things like that to make lists

Comment: Yes I think the issue is that for each iteration of the loop, the list is just reprinted over and over again, just adding a new value every time.  The actual code I'm using is a little too complicated to go through here, but in the above scenario, if "i" is the output I want how could I just create a single table from all the "i" values obtained from the loop?

Comment: @D'Angelo you could start with an empty Image from a ConstantArray and then gradually update the pixels as you go using ReplacePixelValue to draw out the curve pixel-by-pixel . You would need a transformation from your coordinate system to the pixel coordinates of course.

Comment: Making a list of size `1000000` really isn't a problem.  The `For` loop is the problem. Use `Table` to make a list with `i` as the iterator.  Look up `Table` in the documentation for the proper syntax.

Comment: What kind of plot do you expect for a graph with 1 million points? If you take 144 px/inch for the screen resolution, your screen needs to be 6900'' which is around 176 m to fully resolve it. The biggest TV is currently 292'' or 7.4 m. You will need 24 such screens next to each other.

Comment: I would suggest to split your graph into subfigures of manageable size, print them on A4 sheets (1200px/inch) and then glue them together.

Comment: You don't need a massive tv in order to explore a plot  even with with billions of points. Giga-pans like those at http://www.gigapan.com/ are usuable on small screens, so there's no reason you couldn't have a zoomable plot at a low resolution which streamed in the points at an appropriate downsampled granularity. Trading charts do this sort of thing too, allowing you to view the price history of a huge number of points at different time-scales e.g day/week/month/year https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-jpy . The whole series does not need to exist in memory all at once.